# OpenGL Alpha Blend Error after IOS7 update

Tags: ios, opengl-es, ios7

After update to IOS 7 I am seeing an error with images rendering with GL_BLEND enabled and the blend func set to GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA.. I have checked that devices that have not been updated to IOS 7 do not show this problem.

Explanation of what I am seeing.
-Images that have any alpha that is not zero render as non transparent (opaque).

This resulted in show white outlines around art that was blending out to full alpha to hide jagged edges.

[image]

Notice the render artifacts around the each of the parts that make up this little guy.

Another thing to note is that the art images are NOT compressed to PVR4.

Keep in mind again that this all worked pre IOS7 with no graphical errors.

Thanks for you help..

Render Notes:
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendEquation( GL_FUNC_ADD )
glBlendFunc( GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA )

After looking into this.. I have come to think that something has changed with precompiled alpha. I have no idea what could have changed in iOS 7 .. Still working on this.

**Solved** 
My understanding is that the call textureWithContentsOfFile without saying you wanted GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication in our case seemed to still produce a image that had premultiplied alpha.  By adding into the options that YES we wanted it to do so .. everything now on iOS7 is working.

Comment: What have you tried and didn't work? Some guidelines as to how to reproduce your error would be helpful, might mean the difference between getting an answer quickly or not at all.

Comment: Its not a tried or havent tried.. its a case of the engine worked pre IOS7 but now all rendering of alpha is messed up. I have looked thru change lists to our engine it insure no changes that may have happen around the time IOS7 was released but that proved fruitless. I have also went thru to insure the proper setup of OpenGL but this problem persists.

Comment: How are you loading your textures?

Comment: loaderClass = (NSClassFromString(@"GLKTextureLoader")); GLKTextureInfo* info = [loaderClass textureWithContentsOfFile: path.NSStringValue() options: options error: &error];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using for loading textures the method `-textureWithContentsOfFile:options:error` of `GLKTextureLoader`, then you could try adding `GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication` set to `YES` to the options dictionary.

```
NSDictionary * options = @{GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication:@YES};

NSError *err;
GLKTextureInfo *ti = [GLKTextureLoader textureWithContentsOfFile:path options:options error:&err];
```

Comment: Any chance that the default options for textureWithContentsOfFile could have changed with the IOS7 update.. or should I say do you know if they did..?

Comment: I do not know if they did. The documentation states _If the key is not specified, the default value is NO_ in case of apply premultiplication. I only know that the same .png files when loaded under iOS6 where transparent and after switching to iOS7 the transparencies became opaque (white in my case). The textures were fixed after adding 'GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication' explicitly as YES. Unfortunately I cannot easily test this back with iOS6.

Comment: Yes well that did the trick.. I know that pre iOS7 that loading textures in this way produced a precompiled alpha, I dont know if that happen to be a bug that has been around from iOS5 or not. All I know is the seconded I updated All the Game/Apps we produced started to have this problem.  Thanks for the help..

Comment: NSDictionary * options = @{GLKTextureLoaderApplyPremultiplication:@YES};